# Compare VBA dictionaries in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I do a quarterly report comparison on stock. Each item in the report has a reference number and then several data points (Column A has the reference and then B -->>) has the data characteristics.

I wanted to have a quick way of comparing a column on two reports and check two three things, additions (items on the second report not on the first), deletions (items on the first report but not on the second) and changes (items on both reports but where the value in the column I am checking has changed.

Fine idea...

Okay so I put together a dictionary builder which works great:

```
Function CreateStockDictionary(wsNAME As String, refColumn As String, TargetColumn As String, startRow As Long)

Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare 'NON case sensitive

Dim xRange As Range
Dim xCell As Range

Dim EndRow As Long
EndRow = FindLastRow(wsNAME)

Dim RefString As String
Dim TargString As String

RefString = GetRangstring(refColumn, startRow, refColumn, EndRow)
TargString = GetRangstring(TargetColumn, startRow, TargetColumn, EndRow)

Set xRange = Application.Union(Worksheets(wsNAME).Range(RefString), Worksheets(wsNAME).Range(TargString))

i = 1
For i = 1 To EndRow
    dict.Add Key:=xRange(i, 1), Item:=xRange(i, 2)
Next i

Set CreateStockDictionary = dict
Set dict = Nothing

End Function
```

So the above returns a dictionary which has all the things I need. Essentially the reference number has become the key. and the data value in the other column has become the item. So I wrote a script which I thought would compare the two dictionaries created using the above:

```
Sub sbCompareDictionary()

Const wsNameSOY As String = "TEST"
Const wsNameQ1 As String = "TEST2"
Const refColumn As String = "A"
Const compareColumn As String = "B"
Const startRow As Long = 1

Dim returnArray As Variant

Dim SOYDict As Scripting.Dictionary
Set SOYDict = CreateStockDictionary(wsNameSOY, refColumn, compareColumn, startRow)

Dim Q1Dict As Scripting.Dictionary
Set Q1Dict = CreateStockDictionary(wsNameQ1, refColumn, compareColumn, startRow)

Dim OutputDict As Scripting.Dictionary
Set OutputDict = New Scripting.Dictionary


' Check for entries not in both (1st dictionary against 2nd)
For Each xkey In SOYDict.Keys

    If Not Q1Dict.Exists(xkey) Then 'If it doesnt exist in both then flag as missing
        OutputDict.Add xkey, "Not found in " & wsNameQ1
    End If

    If Q1Dict.Exists(xkey) Then ' If it does exist then check for changes
        If SOYDict.Items(xkey) <> Q1Dict.Items(xkey) Then
            OutputDict.Add xkey, "Value has Changed from [" & SOYDict.Items(xkey) & "] To [" & Q1Dict.Items(xkey) & "]"
        End If
    End If

Next xkey


ReDim returnArray(OutputDict.Count, 2)

Counter = 0
For Each Key In OutputDict.Keys
    returnArray(Counter, 0) = Key
    returnArray(Counter, 1) = OutputDict.Item(Key)
    Counter = Counter + 1
Next Key

Set Destination = Worksheets(wsNameSOY).Range("k1")
Destination.Resize(UBound(returnArray, 1), UBound(returnArray, 2)).Value = returnArray

End Sub
```

No the issue appears to be here:

```
' Check for entries not in both (1st dictionary against 2nd)
For Each xkey In SOYDict.Keys

    If Not Q1Dict.Exists(xkey) Then 'If it doesnt exist in both then flag as missing
        OutputDict.Add xkey, "Not found in " & wsNameQ1
    End If

    If Q1Dict.Exists(xkey) Then ' If it does exist then check for changes
        If SOYDict.Items(xkey) <> Q1Dict.Items(xkey) Then
            OutputDict.Add xkey, "Value has Changed from [" & SOYDict.Items(xkey) & "] To [" & Q1Dict.Items(xkey) & "]"
        End If
    End If

Next xkey
```

I have tried a lot of variations but for some reason I cant just cant seem to return values from the Q1Dict

I setup sheet 1 with:

```
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
5   E
```

and sheet 2 with

```
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
5   F
6   E
```

so I should get 6 as missing on sheet one and 5 as changed but it just doesnt work.

I have spent hours trying to figure out why.... please, please... help!

Comment: "If key `xkey` exists and the mapped value mismatches that of the corresponding key in the other dictionary, *add that key again with a new value*" - I'd expect this to throw some "key already exists" error. `Scripting.Dictionary` is quite forgiving. Have you tried removing the existing key before adding it back with a new value?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I am trying to compare dictionaries. Not add or remove values. I am iterating through the keys of dictionary A and checking if those keys exist in Dictionary B. I am using two dictionaries with one intentional discrepancy in key values and the comparison is not working.

Comment: Sorry I totally misread that code. :/

Comment: anyone? help....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better late than never- looks like in the check for entries not in both, you need to add '**.value**' to your Exists and Add methods ...like this:

```
If Not Q1Dict.Exists(xkey.value) Then 'If it doesn't exist in both then flag as missing
    OutputDict.Add xkey.value, "Not found in " & wsNameQ1
End If
```